# Is the conventional current direction assumed to be from - to + in US Air force training videos?

Tags: current, magnetic-flux

1)

https://youtu.be/a8casNPDvI4?t=354

I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting, but I couldn't get past this point in the video as it seems they are assuming the current flows from - to + and its confusing me a lot.

2)

Also in another video they seem to assume the flux direction in a solenoid in reverse to what my textbook says (right hand rule)
https://youtu.be/X0WnddW5gZI?t=208

Are they using a different convention or is my understanding flawed ?

Comment: In the first video, they are using electron (negative) current flow, rather than Conventional (positive) flow.

Comment: @PeterBennett Thank you, it seems they're strictly using the electron flow for current direction. Is this the reason the direction of magnetic field in the second video is in reverse ? Or is my understanding of right hand rule incorrect? they're nice videos, but with the opposite directions for current/magnetic field, I'm finding it a bit confusing to follow..

Comment: If you use electron (negative) current, then you use your left hand instead of your right hand.

Comment: Ah okay I'll give it a try using the left hand. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The US military uses electron current in their electronics training materials.